# Getting an error for unexpected else in bash

Tags: bash, if-statement

[SOLVED]
I'm pretty new tho bash-/shell-scripting and trying setup a check for ip address on a server which gets about once a week a new ip.
The script will then send the new ip to the users.

My problem is, that I'm getting a syntax-error in the last if-else statement for "unexpected" else and can wrap my head around why.

My first iteration didn't use functions, but instead one multi lined if-else which got me the same error. The functions on their own seem to work just fine.

```
#!/bin/bash

# script to send the new server ip to the users

# get the recent ip address of the system
new_ip=$(ip route get 8.8.8.8 | awk -F"src " 'NR==1{split($2,a," ");print a[1]}')

file=old_ip.txt

function ip_mail(){
 source $file
 if [ $new_ip != $old_ip ]
  then
  # email-address changed for obvious reasons
  mail -s "New Server IP" [hidden]@[hidden].com <<< "$new_ip"
  echo "old_ip=$new_ip" > old_ip.txt
  exit 0
  fi
    
    exit 0
}

function set_old(){
 touch old_ip.txt
 echo "old_ip=$new_ip" > old_ip.txt
 exit 0
}

if [ $file ]
then
 ip_mail()
else
 set_old()
fi
```

Comment: `if [ $file ]` should be `if [ -f "$file" ]`

Comment: Use [https://www.shellcheck.net/](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to catch those simple syntax errors ;) Look at the last `if [ $file ]`!

Comment: Additionally, all the `()` are wrong / not needed in bash. It is `function set_old { ... } ` and you call it as `set_old` and not `set_old()`.

Comment: @toydarian : thanks, didn't know that

Comment: Instead of adding [Solved] to the text, it would be great, if you could answer your own question and then (you need to wait a day or two before you can do so) mark your own answer as correct

Comment: You generally shouldn't be using the `function` keyword. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#function_foo.28.29